# Text floating out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a div inside another div that includes a paragraph. How do I prevent the text of the paragraph from floating out of the two divs? It's just one line of text, but i want it to have line breaks when it hits the edges of the parent div. How do i do that with CSS/pure Javascript/JQuery?

```
    <div id="contentdiv">
        <p id="content">'put in the long text here'</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have `float:left` or `right` ? in that case use `clear:both;` 
do you use bootstrap or any other css framework ?

try also `{ word-wrap: break-word; }`

Comment: Any example? Don't understand where is the problem. `Overflow: hidden` to parent? `Clear: both` after floated elements?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Your question so far lacks even the most basic information for us to understand what you are even talking about.

Comment: Better just to see the relevant markup and styles, so that we are playing with a *full deck of cards* here, otherwise we can only take stabs in the dark here. I need an MCVE to reproduce and troubleshoot the issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by using adding this code on your div -

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: yeah and for future make sure you provide more information with your code because question with less information creates difficulties for other members in providing answers to you. Cheers!